# Getting Container IP in a Go application

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, containers

I have a simple Go application running inside a docker container. I wish to get the container IP of that container inside the Go application itself. How can I do that? I am a newbie so please help me out, if this question sounds silly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the hostname using `os.hostname()` function.
Below golang code can give you some idea

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    containerHostname, err := os.Hostname()
}
```

containerHostname variable will have the hostname of the container.